# Google Contacts API call return Response ok but empty JSON

Tags: laravel, google-api, google-contacts-api, guzzle, laravel-socialite

Currently building a Laravel app that uses the Socialite package to successfully authenticate users using their Google credentials. However, I'm trying to make a GET request to the Google server to retrieve a given user's contact list, I have been experimenting a bit on Google oAuth 2 Playground and tried to emulate the same request inside my App. I created the following function :

```
public function getContactList()
{

$client = new \GuzzleHttp\Client();

$email = \Auth::user()->email;

$token = \Session::get('token');

$json = $client->get('https://www.google.com/m8/feeds/contacts/default/full/',  [

    'headers' => [

        'Authorization' => 'Bearer ' . $token,

    ],
]);

dd($json);

return $json;
```

}

Following an endless struggle to get past forbidden responses, I finally get a positive one but it's of no use, there's nothing in the body, decoding it with Json_decode gives null, here's the response :

```
Response {#198 ▼
  -reasonPhrase: "OK"
  -statusCode: 200
  -effectiveUrl: "https://www.google.com/m8/feeds/contacts/default/full/"
  -headers: array:11 [▼
    "expires" => array:1 [▼
      0 => "Mon, 30 Mar 2015 15:19:52 GMT"
    ]
    "date" => array:1 [▼
      0 => "Mon, 30 Mar 2015 15:19:52 GMT"
    ]
    "cache-control" => array:1 [▶]
    "vary" => array:2 [▶]
    "content-type" => array:1 [▶]
    "x-content-type-options" => array:1 [▶]
    "x-frame-options" => array:1 [▶]
    "x-xss-protection" => array:1 [▶]
    "content-length" => array:1 [▶]
    "server" => array:1 [▶]
    "alternate-protocol" => array:1 [▶]
  ]
  -headerNames: array:11 [▼
    "expires" => "Expires"
    "date" => "Date"
    "cache-control" => "Cache-Control"
    "vary" => "Vary"
    "content-type" => "Content-Type"
    "x-content-type-options" => "X-Content-Type-Options"
    "x-frame-options" => "X-Frame-Options"
    "x-xss-protection" => "X-XSS-Protection"
    "content-length" => "Content-Length"
    "server" => "Server"
    "alternate-protocol" => "Alternate-Protocol"
  ]
  -body: Stream {#197 ▼
    -stream: :stream {@8 ▼
      wrapper_type: "PHP"
      stream_type: "TEMP"
      mode: "w+b"
      unread_bytes: 0
      seekable: true
      uri: "php://temp"
      options: []
    }
    -size: null
    -seekable: true
    -readable: true
    -writable: true
    -uri: "php://temp"
    -customMetadata: []
  }
  -protocolVersion: "1.1"
}
```

What can I change or what do I need to change to get the full list of contacts instead of a empty 200 response ?

**UPDATE:** I have made a few tests to verify the accuracy of my requests, and found out that the above request actually return an ATOM feed, which might be the problem. When I made requests to Drive APIs which returned JSON responses, I could extract without any trouble the appropriate data just by parsing it using json_decode. Which function do I need to use to parse ATOM data within PHP to be able to retrieve it ?

Comment: https://www.google.com/search?q=atom+feed+defintion&ie=utf-8&oe=utf-8  Atom is xml based.

Comment: I'm aware of Atom being XML based, my question is : How can I extract the xml/atom from the body of the $json object into a string ?

Comment: If your ATOM feed is embedded within a json response then you can simply use PHP's json decode function http://php.net/manual/en/function.json-decode.php

Answer (score 1):

Have you tried to add the 'alt=json' parameter to your GET request ? Like so :

```
$response = $client->get('https://www.google.com/m8/feeds/contacts/default/full?alt=json',  [
 'headers' => [
   'Authorization' => 'Bearer ' . $token,
 ],
]);
```

I have been trying to get the contacts API in JSON and it looked like this is the proper way :
https://developers.google.com/google-apps/contacts/v3/reference#contacts-query-parameters-reference

Answer (score 0):

You're getting a `Response` object from Guzzle. There is a `json` method available on the `Response` object, so you should be able to:

```
$response = $client->get('https://www.google.com/m8/feeds/contacts/default/full/',  [
    'headers' => [
        'Authorization' => 'Bearer ' . $token,
    ],
]);

echo $response->json();
```

Source: http://guzzle.readthedocs.org/en/latest/http-messages.html#id2